# Android Sqlite inserted data does not persist when app is restarted

Tags: android, sqlite

I have seen similar questions and did the solutions offered, but i am still having trouble. I have an sqlite database and somewhere in my program, i perform an insert operation:

```
dbHelper = MyDBHelper.getInstance(context);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();             

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("listname", "examplelist"); // inserting a string
values.put("productname", textPart); // inserting an int
values.put("productprice", pricePart); // inserting an int// Inserting Row
db.insert("locallist", null, values);
```

At this point, when i query the database, i see that the row has been inserted. Then, i close my app and open it again, and in onCreate method of the main activity, i do the following:

```
MyDBHelper dbHelper;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dbHelper = MyDBHelper.getInstance(this);

    String [] searchResultsByListname = dbHelper.QueryByListName("examplelist");
}
```

but this query returns an empty array. Here is the MyDBHelper class:

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static MyDBHelper mInstance = null;
private static final int DB_VERSION = 5;
private static final String DB_NAME = "database.sqlite";
static final String TABLE_NAME = "PRODUCTS";
private final Context mContext;
private static SQLiteDatabase myWritableDb;

// private static String DATABASE_PATH;

public static MyDBHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MyDBHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        // DATABASE_PATH = ctx.getPackageName();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    createDB();
}

private void createDB() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = DBExists();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        copyDBFromResource();
    }

}

private boolean DBExists() {
    File dbFile = new File(/* DATABASE_PATH + */DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

private void copyDBFromResource() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String dbFilePath = DB_NAME;

    try {
        inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}




    public String[] QueryByListName(String listname) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "select productname, productimage,productprice from locallist where listname = '"+listname+"'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    String[] searchResult= new String[cursor.getCount()];

    String[] searchResultNoFound= new String[1];

    String searchResultSingleLine="";
    int index=0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            searchResultSingleLine += cursor.getString(i) + ";";
        }
        searchResult[index]=searchResultSingleLine; index++;

        searchResultSingleLine="";

    }

    searchResultNoFound[0]="Urun Bulunamadi";

    if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        return searchResult;
    else
        return searchResultNoFound;
}
}
```

I checked whether table exists when app is started, and i am sure that the table exists, but it is empty. So, why my inserted data is not preserved when app is closed? Can anyone help me?

**NOTE:** My database "database" is in my assets folder, and it has two tables: PRODUCTS and locallist. PRODUCTS table is prepopulated and i can use it without any problems, but locallist table is empty at the beginning, and i add data to it at runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DBExists()` method is incorrect. You should be using

```
return mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).exists();
```

As of now, you are overwriting your database with the version from your assets folder upon every restart of your application. Finally, you shuold remove `this.getReadableDatabase();` from your `createDB()` method as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Well, that worked thanks a lot! But i did not understand why it was working fine on my prepopulated table PRODUCTS, but not working on table locallist. You said that i overwrite the database with the version from assets folder, but isn't it okay since i added some data to locallist table? I mean, isn't the inserted data is saved into the database which is in the assets folder?

Comment: Basically what is happening was, you took the DB from your assets folder, created a file, and then wrote to that file. By having the wrong DB exists method, you ended up basically deleting the DB (and all of the new locallist changes), and recopying the products only database version from assets. The assets folder is actually read-only. In fact, you're code is copying the DB to the android database path to solve this very problem.